# Apache2 always times out

Tags: apache2

I am new to Ubuntu and just getting started - love it so far!

However, running into an issue with Apache2 and cannot seem to find a solution in this knowledge base (or elsewhere.)

I followed a digitalocean tutorial, where everything seemed to execute successfully and Ubuntu output matched what was noted in the tutorial.

However, all attempts to bring up the Ubuntu apache2 default page result in a time-out.

As far as I can tell, the apache2 service is up and running fine:

```
:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** How do you connect to the apache2 default page exactly?

Comment: Hello - thank you for the welcome!  I am putting my public IP address into a browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, using your public IP address would require you to have your router configured to forward ports to your local IP. Your connection is timing out because your router/modem is ignoring the request.

If you put `http://localhost/`into your address bar, the test page will come up.  like wise if you use your local IP address from any computer connected to your LAN (local network) it will come up. ex `192.168.2.10`

Port forwarding is different based on the model router you have.  You can search for many tutorials on how to do it.  At the very least you need port 80 forwarded.

EDIT:
I should add that you only need to setup port forwarding if you wish to access your server from the outside world.  This is a bad idea for a development server as you are opening the door to hackers.  If you do need WAN access to the server look into installing and configuring [CSF](https://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html)

Comment: MAGIC! Many thanks, Chad, for the resolution and, also, next steps. (Am on the baby step path ;-)